# How to use ng-repeat in HTML page using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need five independent fields based on the actual price and offer i need to find final price
This is my sample html code

addproduct.html

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="a in [1,2,3,4,5]">
       <tr>
         <th scope="row">{{a}}</th>
         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" style="width:70%; line-height:1.5" ng-model="product.pModel"></td>
         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" style="width:70%; line-height:1.5" ng-model="product.actualPrice" max="2" limit-decimal></td>
         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" style="width:50%; line-height:1.5" ng-model="product.offer" numbers-only></td>        
         <td>
             <label class="checkbox-inline" ng-init="data.check=true">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox" value="option" ng-change="product.availablity = data.check ? '' : 0" ng-model="data.check"> Unlimited
            </label>
        </td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="availablity" name="availablity" ng-disabled="data.check0" ng-model="product.availablity" ></td>
        <td class="text-center"> <b ng-model="finalPrice"  ng-bind="finalPrice=product.actualPrice-(product.actualPrice*product.offer/100)"></b></td>        
      </tr> 

    </tbody>
```

How can i save data in json format using angularjs

When I save the submit button I need the output as

script.json

```
    product : [
            {
                "pModel" : "50gm",
                "actualPrice" : "250",
                "offer" : 0,
                "availablity" : "0"
            },
            {
                "pModel" : "50gm",
                "actualPrice" : "250",
                "offer" : 0,
                "availablity" : "0"
            }
                .....upto 5 fields           
            ]
```

In here when I am entering any one of the field it will affect entire field

Comment: Create a plunker of what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://plnkr.co/edit/b7MRDszD8OSUNtjFamnZ?p=preview) should help you to figure it out.

Your product variable is an array, so you should access it like it's array, not as object - `product[$index].fieldName`